# I can not join EasyAdminBundle

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to join the EasyAdminBundle with another bundle created by me but gives me this error.

Class PersonaBundle\Entity\Person does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Somewhere you have a reference to `PersonaBundle\Entity\Person`.

Try a search in your project after this string.